# HTML Search_Term for more than one product

Tags: php, html, search

I am working on a project and we need an image to direct to specific products. We have selected products on offer and we wish to direct them to the products that are on offer using a search_term. In the HTML we currently use this: `<li><a href="/search?search_term=generator"><img src="/images/jquery-banner/1.jpg" border="0" /></a></li>` however, I want to search for all the products that we have on offer even if they are in different categories.

```
// Get search term
if (isset($_GET["search_term"]))
{
    $search_term = htmlspecialchars($_GET["search_term"]);
    $single_search_term = $search_term;

    // Check for errors in search
    if (strlen(trim($single_search_term)) == 0)
    {
        $search_error = TRUE;
        // Assign page details
        $page_title = 'Search Results';
        $meta_title = "Search Results"; 
        $meta_description = "";
        $meta_keywords = "";
        $category_description = "You haven't entered a valid search term, please try again";
    }
    else
    {
        $search_error = FALSE;
        $search_term = explode(" ", $search_term);

        $x = 0;
        // Loop through each search string and add to query
        foreach ($search_term as $value)
        {
            if ($x == 0)
            {
                $search_term = "(Product_Title LIKE '%" . $value . "%')";
                $x++;
            }
            else
            {
                $search_term .= " AND (Product_Title LIKE '%" . $value . "%')";
                $x++;
            }
        }
```